# Could not format node 'Link' for execution as SQL

Tags: linq-to-sql

```
Table1 with
Name, 
Address
CityID(foreign key from Table2) 

and Table2 with

CityID,
CityName.
```

I am using LINQ to SQL to retrieve data. When I try to oderby CityName I get the following error: **base {System.SystemException} = {"Could not format node 'Link' for execution as SQL."}**

Here's my LINQ code to retrieve data :

```
var Person = from person in db.Table1 
                orderby person.Table2.CityName
                select person;
```

Can someone point me why its causing the above mentioned error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this bug report](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/362759/linq-to-sql-cannot-order-by-delay-loaded-property) and my own testing (I was able to reproduce this), it looks like your `Table2.CityName` property may have `Delay Loaded = True` in the dbml designer.

Apparently **you can't order by a delay-loaded property**, so changing `Delay Loaded` to `False` on your `Table2.CityName` property in the DBML designer should take care of it.

Comment: Thanks Shaun..yes it was delay loading which was causing the problem.